Undefined control sequence with lettrine
I have the following foo.sty:
\ProvidesPackage{foo}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\LettrineOptionsFor{A}{loversize= 0.05,lhang= 0.10,findent= 0.000\LettrineWidth,nindent= 0.50em}

and foo.tex:
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{foo}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}

After compiling, I get the following error as a result:
! Undefined control sequence.
\LettrineOptionsFor ...}\xdef \L@tmpb {\L@initial 
                                                  }\endgroup \ifx \L@tmpa \L...

I do not understand the Undefined control sequence here, considering that if I comment the line with \LettrineOptionsFor..., \lettrine works. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

The package documentation has the following to say about \LettrineOptionsFor:

This command is to be used in an optional config file

It seems to works if you move the \LettrineOptionsFor{...}{...} into a config file:
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}

\renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{Quack.cfl}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Quack.cfl}
\LettrineOptionsFor{A}{
loversize= 0.05,lhang= 0.10,findent= 0.000\LettrineWidth,nindent= 0.50em
}
\end{filecontents*}  

\begin{document}

\lettrine{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}


My bad for not finding this in the documentation. Thanks a lot.

@6c656c You're welcome!

Despite this shocking resort to referencing the documentation, I suspect that this is a bug, it seems unlikely to be intentional. probably worth reporting to the package author.

@DavidCarlisle No idea if this is a bug or feature. The profile of the package author shows "last seen this week", so they will probably see this question.

@DavidCarlisle I agree, it looks weird that the \LettrineOptionsFor command works when included in an external file and not when just added to the preamble. The reason is that the config file is read by the \lettrine command every time, in order to tweak the optional parameters given online.  Putting  \LettrineOptionsFor commands in the preamble is not an option.

@DanielFlipo I'd have thought that it would be quicker to read the file once and save itself in a macro (then the preamble version could directly add to the macro) but I haven't looked at the code:-)

@DavidCarlisle That could be an option, I'll have a look, thanks.

Version 2.70 of the lettrine package is on the way to CTAN. Thanks to @DavidCarlisle hints, it fixes the issue reported here.

@DanielFlipo thanks. If any issues arise I will of course deny any responsibility and blame samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.

@DavidCarlisle Ulrike will be disappointed if you suddenly blame somebody else
